# Error message on confirmation email script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My job uses google apps script to send confirmation emails when a google form has been submitted. We usually use the same script for every form (subbing out subject line and text), but one of the scripts is producing an 100% error rate even though all the other scripts that look identical are running without issue.

Here's the script below:

```
function sendEmail(e) {
     //response
     //getRespondentEmail()
     var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email.html");
     var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();  
     var emailTo = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
     var subject = "Welcome to Mindful-PC";
     var textBody = "This email requires HTML support. Please make sure you open with a client that supports it.";
     var options =  { htmlBody : htmlText } ;
     
     if(emailTo !== undefined){
       GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, textBody,{
       htmlBody : htmlText,
       'from': 'mmhs@challiance.org',
          'replyTo' : 'mmhs@challiance.org'
    });  
 } 
}
```

The stackdriver logs say that: "Invalid argument: mmhs@challiance.org at sendEmail(Code:14:14)"

I'm not sure what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

### `from` must be the primary email or valid alias of the person who runs the script

If you set up a script on a trigger, the code runs authorized as the trigger creator.

Your error indicates that `mmhs@challiance.org` is not a valid alias of the trigger creator.

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))